# Save Value on Sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to insert values into my sqlite database in iPhone application.Insert Value on database insertSQL show nil value. Value Not adding on database.value not insert on create database. First function create database connection and student.db is database name.Second function can be enter the value and called function on class to save data but insertSQL is nil.So value not store in database.but with no success:
Thanks in Advance..

Code..

```
  -(BOOL)createDB{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                                    [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"student.db"]];
    BOOL isSuccess = YES;
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
     const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
     if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
     char *errMsg;
     const char *sql_stmt ="create table if not exists studentsDetail (regno integer primary key, name text, department text, year text)";
   if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
                                != SQLITE_OK)
   {
   isSuccess = NO;
   NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
   }
   sqlite3_close(database);
   return  isSuccess;
   }
   else {
   isSuccess = NO;
   NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
   }
   }
   return isSuccess;
   }
   - (BOOL) saveData:(NSString*)registerNumber name:(NSString*)name
                       department:(NSString*)department year:(NSString*)year;
   {
   const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
   if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
   NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into studentsDetail (regno,name, department, year) values(\"%ld\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",(long)[registerNumber integerValue],name, department, year];
   const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
   sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
   if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
   {
    return YES;
   }
   else {
   return NO;
   }
     sqlite3_reset(statement);
   }
    return NO;
   }       
  -(IBAction)Save:(id)sender {
  BOOL success = NO;
  NSString *alertString = @"Data Insertion failed";
            if (_regNo.text .length>0 &&_name.text.length>0 && _department.text.length>0 &&_year.text.length>0){
                success = [[Sqlite getSharedInstance]saveData:
                           _regNo.text name:_name.text department:
                           _department.text year:_year.text];
  }
  else{
   alertString = @"Enter all fields";
  }
  if (success == NO) {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                      alertString message:nil
                                      delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
  }
  _regNo.text = @"";
  _department.text = @"";
  _name.text = @"";
  _year.text = @"";

 }
```

Comment: use student.sqlite instead of student.db.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check that the prepare statement has actually worked...

```
   if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert,-1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
       NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), sqlite3_errcode(db));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DBManager` class of `NSObject` class

here is the proper implementation :

```
static MyDBManager *sharedInstance = nil;
static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;



@implementation MyDBManager
+(MyDBManager*)getSharedInstance{
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL]init];
        [sharedInstance createDB];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(instancetype) init
{

    [self createDB];

    return self;
}

-(BOOL)createDB{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                    [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyDataBase.db"]];


    NSLog(@"DataBase path : %@",databasePath);

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
  //create section table
            NSString *create_table_section= [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %@(%@ INTEGER ,%@ TEXT ,%@ TEXT  );",TABLE_SECTION,ID,NAME,MODIFIED_DATE];
  const char *sql_stmt_section =[create_table_section UTF8String];


   BOOL check=sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt_section, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
            != SQLITE_OK;
 sqlite3_close(database);

            return  check;
        }
        else {
            return NO;
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Create a Method for inserting data

```
-(BOOL) insertDropdownValues:(NSString *)tableName
                       andId:(NSInteger) dID
                        name:(NSString*) name
                modifiedDate:( NSString*) modifiedDate {

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (%@, %@, %@) values (\"%ld\",\"%@\", \"%@\")",tableName,ID,NAME,MODIFIED_DATE, dID,name,modifiedDate];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];


        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);


        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {

            NSLog(@"Inserted SuccessFull");
                          sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);

            return YES;
        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"Insertion failed !");
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);

            return NO;
        }

    }

    sqlite3_reset(statement);
    return NO;

}
```

Uses :
import `DBManager` class into your class than

```
    MyDBManager *dbManager=[[MyDBManager alloc] init];

// create your method that will Accept your parameters and insert into database  

BOOL check=[dbManager insertDropdownValues:@"tableName"
                           andId:@"you_id"
                            name:@"name"
                    modifiedDate:@"your_date" ]

// you can check if data is inserted or not 

 if(check)
{
 // inserted Successful
}
else
{
  // couldn't insert data 
}
```

I hope this may help you .